# ERC20 Crowdsale, Tokens per ether

Tags: tokens, crowdsale

I am using the zeppelin-solidity. Where is the setting how many tokens you receive for 1 Ether?

And where can I set my Ether account as the receiver account?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's right in the constructor:

```
function Crowdsale(uint256 _startTime, uint256 _endTime, uint256 _rate, address _wallet) public
```

_rate = The number of tokens per wei

_wallet = Address where the funds are collected

Comment: do i have to replace this values with my data or do i have to define this variables ?

Comment: @Keseknedel Those are arguments. you have to give those values which creating the contract.

Comment: so i need to replace the values in the bracket?